# I want to get single line input for a list where it accepts the value upto 'N' which is predefined in python

Tags: python, list

for example :

`n=2`,

list input in a single line must accept two input at max like

enter list val:34 41

`list=[34,41]`

similarly,

`n=6`

enter list:3 2 3 1 3 4

`list=[3,2,3,1,3,4]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.split()` method like this:

```
numbers = input("Enter the numbers separated by a space:")
numbers_lst = numbers.split(' ')
numbers_lst = [int(x) for x in numbers_lst]
print(numbers_lst)
```

Output:

```
Enter the numbers:3 2 3 1 3 4
[3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4]
```

If you want to do it with `N` as you mentioned in the question, then you can make use of a `for loop` like this:

```
n = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter (N):"))
numbers_lst = []
numbers = input("Enter the numbers separated by a space:")
numbers_lst = numbers.split(' ')

if len(numbers_lst) > n:
    print("Length exceeded")
else:
    numbers_lst = [int(x) for x in numbers_lst]
    print(numbers_lst)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**You could just get the entire line and just store the first n elements in another list like this**

```py
n = 2
numbers = list(map(int,input().split()))
first_n_numbers = numbers[:n]
print(first_n_numbers)
```

**Input:**

```
2 3 5 7 2 5
```

**Output:**

```
[2,3]
```

Comment: No matter how many values the user enters only the first n elements will be stored in 
 **first_n_numbers**.